# Using JQuery .append() to dynamically change table layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, append

I am using an HTML table but I want to dynamically change the layout of the table based on the browser size. My basic code looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <td class="row">E1</td>
  <td class="row">E2</td>
  <td class="row">E3</td>
  <td class="lastRow">E4</td>
</tr>
```

Then the JQuery should calculate the number of rows and insert row-breaks accordingly.
My JQuery looks like this for now:

```
$('td.row').append('</tr><tr>');
```

Yet, its still displaying all the elements on one line. Any idea why?

Comment: Don't do this.  Changing the elements simply for layout breaks the whole concept of separation of elements from style.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect place to use fluid CSS layouts.

Instead of writing lots of crazy Dom-manipulating javascript, simply replace your `TD` tags with `divs` and have them `float:left`

Further- `append` does not do what you think it does.  It's `dom` manipulation and not string manipulation- you can't use it to directly change HTML the way you're thinking.

[Further reading](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at .after(); function:

http://api.jquery.com/after

Answer (score 0):

i think that you need to try with this selector

Asumming that your table haved an id called `example` try like this

```
$("#exmaple tr:last").append('<tr></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('</tr><tr>').insertAfter('.row');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to do your append on the tr element, not on td.row

Answer (score 0):

You need to *not* think in terms of constructing HTML markup. There's no way to splice a closing/opening `</tr><tr>` into the DOM (without some ugly `.innerHTML` hacks).

Instead, create a new row after the current row, and the relocate the cells into that new row.

```
var row_cells = $('td.row').slice(1);

row_cells.each( function( i, el ) {
    $('<tr>').insertAfter( row_cells.eq(i).parent() )
             .append( row_cells.eq(i) );
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/EDf5a/

---

Or maybe you wanted a new row for each cell:

```
var row_cells = $('td.row');
var row = row_cells.parent();

row_cells.each(function(i, el) {
    $('<tr>').insertBefore(row)
        .append(row_cells.eq(i));
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/EDf5a/1/

Comment: @Barry: I had to guess at what the final result was meant to by. Wasn't sure what you meant by *"accordingly"*. I assumed you wanted the last cell to be in its own row. If that's not right, please describe the desired outcome. EDIT: Maybe you meant one row per cell. I'll give an update.

Comment: Embrace Stack Overflow as a community of enlightened discourse and refrain from enabling poor design decisions with stunt code.

Comment: @RSG: [Please keep discourse polite.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette) If you disagree with my decision to answer the specific question instead of offering possible alternatives, that's fine. And if you want to down-vote me for it, that's fine as well. But keep it civil. I don't believe we know enough  about the situation to know what the best solution is. That's why I chose to give a solution focused on the specific inquiry. If you feel that the question is an example of the *X Y Problem*, then please petition the OP for more information by commenting on the question, not on my answer.

Comment: You are of course right.  Enlightened discourse must be civil, and my tone was not constructive.  I apologize.